# How to go to next line after every row in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I need to come up with something like this: It's a layout of seats on an airplane.

> 1 A B C D
>
> 2 A B C D
>
> 3 A B C D
>
> 4 A B C D
>
> 5 A B C D
>
> 6 A B C D
>
> 7 A B C D

But instead my code prints this:

> ABCD
>
> ABCABCD
>
> ABCABCD
>
> ABCABCD
>
> ABC

This is my code, any help would be really appreciated. I just started working with arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                             {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

     for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
     {

            for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
            {
                 cout<<airplane[i][j];
                 if (airplane[i][j]=='D')
                 {
                     cout<<endl;
                 }
            }
     }

     system ("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inner loop should loop up to 4 and outer loop should loop up to 7. For the number, it should be easy enough so do it yourself.

Comment: You made mistake, airplane[i][j] so the for (int i=0; i<7; i++) not <4, either with for (int j=0; j<4; j++) not j<7

Comment: Thx for your help, how did I not think of switching my loops. also is there any other way to do it without the if loop because I am gonna be modifying characters inside the array but I want it to print a new line line after every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code :

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    {
         char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                                 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

         for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
         {
             cout << i+1;
                for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
                {
                     cout<<airplane[i][j];
                     if (airplane[i][j]=='D')
                     {
                         cout<<endl;
                     }
                }
         }

         system ("PAUSE");
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..:-->

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

 for (int i=0; i<7; i++)       //Row
 {
        cout<<i+1;
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++)    //Column
        {
             cout<<airplane[i][j];
             cout<<" "; 
        }
     cout<<endl;
 }

 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop in this fashion

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
     {
            cout<<i+1;
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                cout<<' ';
                 cout<<airplane[i][j];                

            }
            cout<<endl;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your outer loop for 7 times and inner loop for 4 times. Include  cout<

And by the way the code given by Bui Akinori is buggy for if you change the number of seats in each row to five.

Comment: Try running your outer loop for 7 times and inner loop for 4 times. Include cout<<endl; in the outer loop and cout<<" "; in the inner loop. I think a verbal explanation could help you more.

And by the way the code given by Bui Akinori is buggy for if you change the number of seats in each row to five